# convert datetime.datetime value to System.DateTime value in Python

Tags: python

i have a datetime.datetime value, need to convert to System.DateTime value, i only saw the solution of converting from System.DateTime value to datetime.datetime value

Comment: `System.DateTime`? As in the dotnet type? Provide a proper [mcve]

Comment: yes, System.DateTime as .NET type, i figured out: first use DateTime constructor to "convert" from datetime values, and then use SpecifyKind method to set local